# Any good way to handle VOB files in C#?

Tags: c#, directshow, video-processing, dvd, vob

We are trying to load a DVD scan it and extract some information.

To extract the information we need to take a snapshot and run some image analysis.

So far we were using the DirectShow framework and got almost all of the features to work.

The major issue is handling an encrypted DVD. We can't make it fast forward, run backwards or any other navigation function.

Is there a way to convert or deencrypt VOB files in C# ?

Is there a better ( higher level ) framework to use other than DirectShow ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What specific issues are you having with controlling the playback (ff, rewind, etc?).

One issue you may have is the SampleGrabber does not work with VIDEOINFOHEADER2 (format desc that DVDs use), so you may have to write your own SampleGrabber-like filter.  Also, IMediaDet uses SampleGrabber internally, so that probably won't work for you either.

-Jer

Comment: Thanks, but how do i go about writing a custom filter or samplegrabber ?
I read a lot of fourms, but no one gives a clear code example.

Comment: I'd download the Windows SDK and check out: \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\dump

Dump is a renderer code sample.  It will give you any sample.  You will have to modify it to fit your design though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jer, but the sample won't even build.

Basically i want to display a dvd and navigate to specific locations in it and capture the frames into image files.

It sounds simple, but i can't find any .Net code that can acomplish this... 

Do you know of any good code smaples ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe by using libvlc bindings?